# Script for converting object of arrays with objects into an enum (typescript)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, enums

I want to convert an object ofarray with objects into an enum. I'm using TypeScript
Here is a snippet:

```
const data = {
 TERRITORIES: [
  { 'slug': 'world', 'label': 'World'},
   ...
 ],
MEDIAS: [
  { 'slug': 'pay-tv', 'label': 'Pay-TV' },
   ...
]
}
```

I know that TypeScript is doing something like this if you create an enum:

```
var SomeEnum;
(function (SomeEnum) {
    SomeEnum[SomeEnum["A"] = 0] = "A";
    SomeEnum[SomeEnum["B"] = 1] = "B";
    SomeEnum[SomeEnum["C"] = 2] = "C";
    SomeEnum[SomeEnum["D"] = 3] = "D";
})(SomeEnum || (SomeEnum = {}));
```

The expected result should be, that the `slug` is the key and the value is the `label`.

```
enum Territories {
world = 'World',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to create a script that converts an array of objects to an Enum in a dynamic way (like creating a typescript function that converts an array of objects to an Enum).

Like the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) says:

> Enums allow us to define a set of named constants

Since you want to create an Enum dynamic and based on the sentence above, I don't think that is possible to create a script which converts an array of objects to an Enum.

Moreover, I don't think in an architecture perspective is correct either.